# core i5 and wcf problems

Tags: .net, wcf

Please help me to resolve the communication error. When i trying to connect to wcf service from client the exceptions occurs:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   An error (Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This
>   is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt..) occurred while
>   transmitting data over the HTTP
>   channel.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: Attempted to read or write
>   protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is
>   corrupt..
>   ---> System.AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: i5 CPU has nothing to do with your error, I've seen wcf services running fine on i3, i5 or i7

Comment: thanks a lot, but this problem occurs when I installing the service on the server with i5 processor. The same OS (windows 2003 server x64) on the computer with core 2 duo and the i5 processors, the computer with core 2 duo processor work fine, but the computer with i5 processor take an exception like that

Answer (score 0):

This exception probably forwarded down from server.

Debug your server instead, client system has nothing to do with it.

Could be, that you mix x32 & x64 native libraries (i had similar error with Oracle x64 client from x32 assembly).

Comment: thanks a lot, but this problem occurs when I installing the service on the server with i5 processor. The same OS (windows 2003 server x64) on the computer with core 2 duo and the i5 processors, the computer with core 2 duo processor work fine, but the computer with i5 processor take an exception like that

Comment: There is something else different, besides processor. Check database drivers, network drivers, etc.
Could be database codepage, unicode or not (I had similar problems with oracle blobs using unicode, buggy DevArt drivers)

Comment: I try to install the service and the client on the same computer with i5 and the same errors occurs and when i working without service the database driver work properly, what any other idea can you give mi please??

Comment: @LexLavnikov How did you solve the error with Oracle x64/32?  I'm facing same issue...but it's working on one server not the other...no idea whats different on them!